Show that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable.
Let $f$ be a non-negative Lebesgue measurable function on $E\mathbb{E}$. For any $\epsilon>0$, there is measurable subset $E_\epsilon\subset E$ so that $m(E-E_\epsilon)<\epsilon$ and $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{E_\epsilon} f(x)dx$ exists and finite. Show that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable.

I read the proof but I am a little bit confused.
We choose $\epsilon_k=2^{-k}$ so that $E_k\subset E$ with $m(E-E_k)<2^{-k}$. Define $F_k=\cap_{n=k}^\infty E_n$. Clearly, $F_k\subset F_{k+1}$ and $f(x)\chi_{F_k}\ge 0$ and increasing for each $x$.
So by Monotone convergence theorem
$$
0\le \int_E f(x)dx=\int_E\lim_{k\to\infty} f(x)\chi_{F_k}(x)dx=\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_Ef(x)\chi_{F_k}(x)dx=\lim_{k\to\infty} \int_{F_k}f(x)dx\le \lim_{k\to\infty} \int_{E_k}f(x)dx
$$
Question 1: how to get $f(x)=\lim_{k\to\infty} f(x)\chi_{F_k}(x)$?
Question 2: why the last limit is finite?
Question 3: In the solution, why do we need to prove that
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty} m(F_k)=m(E)?
$$
(Using the fact that $m(E)\ge m(F_k)=m(E)-m(E-F_k)\to m(E)$)

Question1  is only true ae. Question 2 is answered by one of the assumptions.

@copper.hat I am still confused about the question 1. I do not know why the first equality holds in the first display. That is my question


Question 1: How to get $f(x) = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f(x)\chi_{F_k}(x)$ ?

In fact, this is only true almost everywhere. Let $F = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} F_k$. If $x \in F$ then, $\exists k_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \in F_{k_0}$. Since $(F_k)$ is increasing, $x \in F_k \ \forall k \ge k_0$, i.e $\chi_{F_k}(x) = 1 \ \forall k \ge k_0$, which is equivalent to $f(x) = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f(x)\chi_{F_k}(x)$.
If $x \not\in F$, that is $x \in E - F$, we have
$$
     E - F = \bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} (E - F_k)
$$
Thus,
$$
    m(E - F) \le m(E - F_k) \le \sum_{n = k}^\infty 2^{-n} \ \forall k \in \mathbb{N}
$$
But the series $\sum_n 2^{-n} < \infty$, therefore, $\sum_{n \ge k} 2^{-n} \rightarrow 0$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$. Therefore, $m(E - F) = 0$.

Question 2: Why the last limit is finite?

In the assumption, we have
$$
    \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \int_{E_\epsilon} f(x)dx
$$
exists and finite. Thus,
$$
    \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_{E_k} f(x)dx
$$
exists and finite (notice in the proof, $E_k = E_{\epsilon_k}, \epsilon_k = 2^{-k}$)

Question 3: In the solution, why do we need to prove that
$$
     \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} m(F_k) = m(E) \ ?
$$

You can use this limit to show $m(E - F) = 0$ instead of what I did in question 1.
